# Storybook not passing correct attribute type to child component

Tags: angular, storybook

I have a storybook instance of ComponentA which is using my CustomDropdownComponent. The `options` attribute is of type `DropdownOption[]` which is correct when I'm running outside of storybook. But in storybook when passing the dropdownOptions from ComponentA to CustomDropdown I'm receiving the type `string` instead of `DropdownOptions[]`.  What have I missed?

ComponentA.stories.ts:

```
export default {
    title: 'Components/ComponentA',
    component: ComponentA,
    decorators: [
        moduleMetadata({
            imports: [CommonModule, CustomDropdownComponent],
        }),
    ],
} as Meta;

const MyTemplate: Story<ComponentA> = (args: ComponentA) => ({
    props: args,
});

export const english = MyTemplate.bind({});
```

ComponentA ts

```
    public dropdownOptions: DropdownOption[] = [
        { id: 'day', type: 'text' },
        { id: 'week', type: 'text' },
    ];

    ngOnInit(): void {
      console.log(typeof dropdownOptions); // Has type "Object" which is correct
    }
```

ComponentA html

```
    <custom-dropdown
        [options]="dropdownOptions"
    ></custom-dropdown>
```

CustomDropdown ts

```
    @Input() public options: DropdownOption[] = [];
     
    ngOnInit(): void {
      console.log(typeof options); // Has type "string" :(
    }
```